# Delete amended_from from employee table at Erpnext

Tags: erpnext

If I delete **amended_from** field from employee table then any problem for ERP?
amended_from is creating problem during new employe create.

Thanks,
Arif

Answer (score 0):

> If I delete amended_from field from employee table then any problem
>   for ERP?

Was the DocType Employee submittable for you by default ? Check if in Employee's DocType record, `Is Submittable` is checked or not. Because as far as I know this field is available only for submittable documents.